# PHP E-mail form subject population array only working half way

Tags: php, forms, email

I have two forms set up on my website but they are using the same Form Handler php file, as such, i've created code to have it determine either the select topic selected or populate with a generic title for the other form, for some reason it was working, but now i can only get the last two items of the array to properly work, the first give me blank subject in email and hang up the form. code below:

PHP snippet:

```
    if(isset($_POST['Message-Topic']))
        {
            $Topics = array (
                "The Want List" => "Want List",
                "Sell a Car" => "Sell a Car",
                "Consignment Program" => "Consignment Program",
                "General Information" => "General Inquiry");
            $Topic = $Topics[$_POST['Message-Topic']];
        } 
    elseif(isset($_POST['Subject'])) 
        {
            $Topic = "Buyer Inquiry";
        }

    $this->mailer->Subject = $Topic;
```

HTML snippet:

```
<select placeholder="Message Topic" name="Message-Topic" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Topic</option>
    <option value="Want List">The Want List</option>
    <option value="Sell a Car">Sell a Car</option>
    <option value="Consignment Program">Consignment Program</option>
    <option value="General Information">General Information</option>
</select>
```

Let me know if I can provide anything else, thanks!

Comment: That's not enough code to determine your issue.

Comment: well you have `The Want List` and `Want List` - they will not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correcting the obvious discrepency between the first option and it's counterpart in the `$Topics` array and a little tweaking to remove spaces it appears to work fine for selecting the topic. As you do a `lookup` to fetch the final topic the values in the select & keys in the array are quite arbitrary - they need not match or even closely replicate the value used in the mailer application. The below stops with a printout of how that mailer might be assigned the value..

```
<?php

    $topic = false;


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        if( isset( $_POST['Message-Topic'] ) ) {

            $choice=$_POST['Message-Topic'];

            $topics = array (
                "want_list"             => "The Want List",
                "sell_car"              => "Sell a Car",
                "consignment_program"   => "Consignment Program",
                "general_information"   => "General Inquiry"
            );

            $topic = array_key_exists( $choice, $topics ) ? $topics[ $choice ] : false;

        }elseif( empty( $_POST['Message-Topic'] ) ){
            $topic='General Enquiry';

        } elseif( isset( $_POST['Subject'] ) ) {
            $topic = "Buyer Inquiry";
        }

        #$this->mailer->Subject = $topic;
        exit( printf( '$this->mailer->Subject = "%s";',$topic ) );
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <select name="Message-Topic" required>
                <option hidden disabled selected>Select your Topic
                <option value="want_list">The Want List
                <option value="sell_car">Sell a Car
                <option value="consignment_program">Consignment Program
                <option value="general_information">General Information
            </select>

            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm relatively new getting back into PHP etc...and I found a highly thorough and secure form with validations and captcha's to use, was doing alright up until this point, but my lack of knowledge and understanding made it so I wasn't even aware of this answer. Thank you @RamRaider for the help and the fix!

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to offer a useful response to help you on the way. Good luck with the rest of the coding adventure